# Script Tool Automation of Search and Update Cursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-script-tool, runtimeerror

I keep recieving the following error:

```
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT [ID_NUMBER,COLLECTION,COLLECTED_,COLLECTI_1], OBJECTID FROM OFFICIAL_STRUCTURES2015]
```

[image]

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
import SSUtilities as UTILS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#print "PRIOR QA DATA TRANSFER: STRUCTURES"
def resetFieldList(InitialFieldList):
    FieldList = "[" + InitialFieldList.replace(";", ",") + "]"
    #FieldList = InitialFieldList.replace(";", ",")
    return FieldList

def PriorQA_StructureData(Input_Str_FC, Input_FieldsList , Update_Str_FC , Update_FieldsList):
    Input_FieldsList = resetFieldList(Input_FieldsList)
    Update_FieldsList = resetFieldList(Update_FieldsList)
    valueDictOfficialStr = {readRow3[0]:(readRow3[1:]) for readRow3 in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(Input_Str_FC, Input_FieldsList)}
    updateStrList = []
    with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(Update_Str_FC, Update_FieldsList) as updateRows_Str:  
        for updateRow1 in updateRows_Str:  
            # store the Join value of the row being updated in a keyValue1 variable  
            keyValue1 = updateRow1[0]
            # verify that the keyValue1 is in the Dictionary  
            print "keyValue1:             ", keyValue1
            print "updateRow1:            ", updateRow1        
            if keyValue1 in valueDictOfficialStr:  
                print "keyValue1 -V2:         ", keyValue1
            # transfer the values stored under the keyValue from the dictionary to the updated fields.  
                if valueDictOfficialStr[1] != ("<null>" or " "):
                    for nullNoMore in range (1,len(Update_FieldsList)): 
                        updateRow1[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialStr[keyValue1][nullNoMore-1]  
                        print "updateRow1[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow1[nullNoMore]
                        updateStrList.append(updateRow1[nullNoMore])

                    updateRows_Str.updateRow(updateRow1)
                    print "updateRow1:  ",updateRow1
        return updateStrList
    del valueDictOfficialStr    


#INPUT: Script tool arguments (Global Variables)

Input_Str_FC = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(0)                                      #    1st Parameter: Input Feature Source Info
Input_FieldsList = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(1)
Update_Str_FC = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(2)                                     #    1st Parameter: Feature Class to Updated
Update_FieldsList = ARCPY.GetParameterAsText(3)

#Environment(s):
desc = ARCPY.Describe(Input_Str_FC)
workSpace = r"" + desc.path
ENV.workspace = workSpace

"""   ===============================================================================
FUNCTIONS:                                                                     """
updateStrList = PriorQA_StructureData(Input_Str_FC, Input_FieldsList , Update_Str_FC , Update_FieldsList) 

"""
===============================================================================
OUTPUT TABLE CREATION: Updated ===============================================================================
# Create Output Text Table
# So the input and output can be reported in the tool report window
"""
header = "Update: Prior Structure History: Company, Date, and GPS Device Utilizated"

row1  = ["| WORKSPACE:                               " , workSpace]
row2  = ["|                                          "]
row3  = ["| INPUT STATEMENTS:                        "]
row4  = ["|   Input Structures Field Class:          " , Input_Str_FC]
row5  = ["|   Input Structure Fields:                " , Input_FieldsList]
row6  = ["|   Structure Field Class To Be Updated:   " , Update_Str_FC]
row7  = ["|   Structure Fields To Be Updated:        " , Update_FieldsList]
row8 =  ["|                                          "]
row9 =  ["| OUTPUT STATEMENTS:                       "]
row10 = ["|   List of Updated Row Values:                "]
total = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10]
for strRow in updateStrList:
    total.append([strRow])

tableOut = UTILS.outputTextTable(total,header=header,pad=1)
ARCPY.AddMessage(tableOut)
```

The HardCode Listed below works, but when I tried to convert it to a script tool it keeps breaking.

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
#import SSUtilities as UTILS
"""
===============================================================================
Environment(s)
=======================
#**TEST ENVIRONMENT** ON COMPUTER DESKTOP"""
workspaceTEST = r"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\TESTSTRM_SWR.gdb"
ENV.workspace = workspaceTEST
"""
===============================================================================
Variables
========="""
#**TEST**
str15096 = workspaceTEST + "\STRUCTURES_15096"
strOfficial = workspaceTEST + "\OFFICIAL_STRUCTURES2015"
fieldsStrOfficial = ["ID_NUMBER", "COLLECTION","COLLECTED_","COLLECTI_1"]
#                        ID           DATE         BY         EQUIPMENT
"""
===============================================================================
"""
print "UPDATE: STRUCTURES_15096" #Initial Print Test
#==============================================================================
#CURSOR CREATION AND UTILIZATION
#===============================
# Used list comprehension to build a dictionary from a data access SearchCursor  
valueDictOfficialStr = {readRow3[0]:(readRow3[1:]) for readRow3 in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(strOfficial, fieldsStrOfficial)}
fieldsStr15096 = ["ID"  , "COLLECTION_DATE" , "COLLECTED_BY" , "COLLECTION_EQUIPMENT"]
with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(str15096, fieldsStr15096) as updateRows_Str15096:  
    for updateRow1 in updateRows_Str15096:  
        # store the Join value of the row being updated in a keyValue1 variable  
        keyValue1 = updateRow1[0]
        # verify that the keyValue1 is in the Dictionary  
        print "keyValue1:             ", keyValue1
        print "updateRow1:            ", updateRow1        
        if keyValue1 in valueDictOfficialStr:  
            print "keyValue1 -V2:         ", keyValue1
        # transfer the values stored under the keyValue from the dictionary to the updated fields.  
            if valueDictOfficialStr[keyValue1][1] != ("<null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsStr15096)): 
                    updateRow1[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialStr[keyValue1][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow1[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow1[nullNoMore]
                updateRows_Str15096.updateRow(updateRow1)
                print "updateRow1:  ",updateRow1
del valueDictOfficialStr
```

Comment: your resetFieldList is returning the wrong format (string, not list). Just use  Input_FieldsList .split(";") to get the field names into a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The required input for field names on a cursor is a list of fields and your function `resetFieldList` is returning a string, not a list. 
Try something like this:

```
def resetFieldList(InitialFieldList):
    FieldList = InitialFieldList.split(";") # split method returns a list
    return FieldList
```